# Connection refused when try convert html to pdf in AWS ubuntu, But works File in Local env

Tags: python-3.x, django, linux, amazon-web-services, pdf-generation

I am trying to convert HTML to pdf in a Django project it works fine on my local computer but when I uploaded it on my AWS ec2 instance it's giving me  **[Errno 111] Connection refused**

**html_to_pdf function**

```
def render_to_pdf(template_src, context_dict={}):
template = get_template(template_src)
html  = template.render(context_dict)

result = BytesIO()
pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(BytesIO(html.encode("ISO-8859-1")), result)
if not pdf.err:
    return HttpResponse(result.getvalue(), content_type='application/pdf')
return None
```

Error in Django
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

so I figure out Basically `pisa.pisaDocument` when parsing the HTML template was looking for an image that I have attached for the logo, but the logo was attached in local environment, so when `pisa.pisaDocument` request that image from my local computer ('http://locahost:8000/static/logo.png') wasn't successful and the connection was refused :)